# Chek the return from a promise function before proceeding. Wrong approach?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, promise

Background: I have a PHP background and this is my first application using MEAN stack.

I need to save a record but before I must to check if there is any record under the same id already saved in the DB.
In PHP I would do something like this:
Once the user clicks "Save":
1) Call the function to check if an entry with that id already exists
2) If it doesnt, call the save function.

In Javascript, I'm getting a little confused with Promises and so on.

Can somebody give me some light here?

Right now, I'm doing the following:
In the save api, I call this function to check if the record already exists in the DB:
`recordExists = findTranscationByBill(billId);`

```
function findTransactionByBill(billId){
     results = new promise(function(resolve, reject){
        Transactions.find({billId : billId},function(err, transactions){
            if(err)
                reject("Error: "+err);

            //console.log(transactions);
            resolve(transactions);
         });  
     });

     results.then(function(data){
        console.log('Promise fullfilled: '+ data);
     }, function(error){
        console.log('Promise rejected: ' + error);
     }); 

  return $results;
}
```

The problem is that I think I'm not using promise properly, as my variable doesn't get populated (because its Async).
In the console.log I see that the promise is being fulfilled however, the variable returns as `[object Object]` 
I'm stucked with this problem because I don't know if I should carry on thinking as PHP mindset or if there is a different approach used in Javascript.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion you could just as well use a callback for this, and since MongoDB has a count method, why not use it

```
function findTransactionByBill(billId, callback){

    Transactions.count({billId : billId}, function(err, count){
        if (err) {
            callback(err, false);
        } else {
            callback(null, count !== 0);
        }
    });

}
```

and to use it

```
findTransactionByBill(billId, function(err, exists) {
   if (err) {
      // handle errors
   } else if ( ! exists ) {
      // insert into DB
   }
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. Remember that promises **are** great, they get you out of callback hell, but at the same time, just plain old callback is how most things are done in Node, and they work just fine for simple convenience methods like this one.

Comment: I disagree, promises are never great if you are using them like the OP was because you are still doing callbacks (with all the drawbacks) but with added ceremony. Deferred anti-pattern is real.

Answer (score 0):

I think the right function is:

```
function findTransactionByBill(billId){
  var results = new promise(function(resolve, reject){
     Transactions.find({billId : billId},function(err, transactions){
        if(err) {
           reject(err);
        } else { 
           if (transactions.length === 0) {
              reject('No any transaction');
           } else {
             //console.log(transactions);
             resolve(transactions);
           }
     });  
 });

 results.then(function(data){
    console.log('Promise fullfilled: '+ data);
 }, function(error){
    console.log('Promise rejected: ' + error);
 }); 

 return results;
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
recordExists = findTranscationByBill(billId);
recordExists.then(function() {
    // resolved, there are some transactions
}, function() {
    // rejected. Error or no any transactions found
    // may be you need to check reject result to act differently then no transactions and then error
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using mongodb native drive.

I think mongodb doesn't have promise built-in supported. So you have to **promisify** it by a little help from promise library. Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23771853/how-can-i-promisify-the-mongodb-native-javascript-driver-using-bluebird) if you want to use bluebird.

After promisifying, the code should looks like that (using bluebird):

```
Promise = require('bluebird');
// Promisify...
var _db = null;
var client = MongoClient.connectAsync('mongodb://localhost:27017/test')
    .then(function(db) {
        _db = db
        return db.collection("myCollection").findOneAsync({ id: 'billId' })
    })
    .then(function(item) {
      if (item)
        _db.save(item);
    })
    .catch (err) {
      // error handling 
    }
```

The above code is not perfect, because it introduced a global var, so the better version may be

```
Promise = require('bluebird');
// Promisify...
var client = MongoClient.connectAsync('mongodb://localhost:27017/test')
    .then(function(db) {
        return Promise.prop({ 
          item: db.collection("myCollection").findOneAsync({ id: 'billId' }, 
          db: db
        })
    })
    .then(function(result) {
      var item = result.item;
      var db = result.db
      if (item)
        db.save(item);
    })
    .catch (err) {
      // error handling 
    }
```

You need to check [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md) to know how to use it. Also they are many other promise libraries like q, when, but all are similar stuff.