# Promisified MongoDB Node driver throwing stack_overflow error on document insert

Tags: node.js, mongodb, promise, bluebird

When promisifying the mongodb driver module, I can insert multiple documents to a collection successfully. However, I'm also getting a stack_overflow Error hitting the catch block.

My approach is based on the answer to this question:
[Mongodb node driver 2.0.* with Bluebird 2.9.* promisification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29118835/mongodb-node-driver-2-0-with-bluebird-2-9-promisification)

I'm promisifying mongodb like this:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird'),
    mongodb = Promise.promisifyAll(require('mongodb'));
```

My code looks like this:

```
mongodb.connectAsync("mongodb://myconnection").then(function(db) {
    return db.collection("collection").insertManyAsync([{a: 1}, {b: 2}]);
}).then(function(result) {
    console.log('info', result);
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.log('error', err);
});
```

The error caught in the catch block (after `then(function(result{})` has been executed every time) has type "stack_overflow".

I tried using just the insert method (`insertAsync()` in this case), but that has the same results.

Comment: Please open an issue with how to reproduce this (try to reduce this as much as you can) in the issue tracker, this smells like a bug.

Comment: Thanks - I've opened issue 605 in the bluebird library github https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/issues/605