# Using native ES6 promises with MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, babeljs, es6-promise

I'm aware that the Node driver for Mongo can be [promisified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23771853/how-can-i-promisify-the-mongodb-native-javascript-driver-using-bluebird) using external libraries. I was curious to see if ES6 promises could be used with `MongoClient.connect`, so I tried this (using Babel 5.8.23 to transpile):

```
import MongoClient from 'mongodb';

function DbConnection({
  host = 'localhost',
  port = 27017,
  database = 'foo'
}) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    MongoClient.connect(`mongodb://${host}:${port}/${database}`, 
    (err, db) => {
      err ? reject(err) : resolve(db);
    });
  });
}

DbConnection({}).then(
  db => {
    let cursor = db.collection('bar').find();
    console.log(cursor.count());
  },
  err => {
    console.log(err);
  }
);
```

The output is `{Promise <pending>}`. Anything to do with cursors seems to yield a similar result. Is there a way to get around this or am I barking up the wrong tree entirely?

Edit: node version 4.1.0.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is nothing to get around, this is the expected behavior. `cursor.count()` returns a promise, if you want the value, you need to use `.then`, e.g.

```
DbConnection({}).then(
 db => {
    let cursor = db.collection('bar').find();
    return cursor.count();
  }
}).then(
  count => {
    console.log(count);
  },
  err => {
    console.log(err);
  }
);
```

or simplified

```
DbConnection({}).then(db => db.collection('bar').find().count()).then(
  count => console.log(count),
  err => console.log(err)
);
```

Comment: Good grief. Thanks, apparently I've been staring at it for too long!

Comment: We all have those times :)

Comment: IME, no need for `err => { console.log(err }` - just put `console.log` in the `.then` error parameter

Answer (score 0):

Another syntax for the response of loganfsmyth (thanks by the way)

```
cursor.count().then(function(cursor_count){
  if(cursor_count){
    // use cursor
  }else{
    // no results
  }
}
```