# Promise's state is in pending although it's in then method

Tags: node.js, es6-promise

I have an issue with promises.

```
mongoDb.getFromDb(req.body.firstName, req.body.lastName)
     .then(
           rows => {
                    console.log(rows.count()); // Promise { <pending> }
           }
      }
```

The log is: `Promise { <pending> }`.

I read about this state:

```
Pending - until a Promise is fulfilled it is in pending state
```

That's why, I use `.then()` method.

As I read, `.then()` method takes a function that will be passed the resolved value of the Promise **once it is fulfilled**.

So if it was fulfilled, why is the state pending?

If it's relevant, this is `getFromDb` function:

```
// Use connect method to connect to the Server
function init() {
  connectingDb = new Promise(
    function (resolve, reject) {
      MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
        if (err) {
          console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
          reject(err);
        }
        else {
          console.log('Connection established to', url);

          resolve(db);
        }
      });

    }
  );
}
```

**UPDATE #1 (`torazaburo`'s comment):**

```
function getFromDb(firstName, lastName) {

    return connectingDb
                       .then(myDb => {
                                      return myDb.collection('alon').find({
                                        "firstName": firstName,
                                        "lastName": lastName
                                      })
                       })
                       .catch(err=> { return err; })
}
```

(I'm still getting `Promise { <pending> }`)

**Update #2 (`noisypixy`'s comment):**

var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

Thanks.

Comment: Although not directly related to your problem, in `getFromDb` you do not need to say `new Promise`; you can simply `return connecdtingDb.then...`, and inside it just return the resulting value instead of calling `resolve()` with it. By the way, are you sure that `find` returns a promise?

Comment: You are right, it doesn't return a promise.
I've updated my topic.
Thanks.

Comment: I can't confirm this unless you explain what is `MongoClient`, but... are you sure `rows` is not a **cursor** or something similar? In that case it would make sense for `rows.count()` to return a promise.

Comment: Yes, you are right.
It returns a cursor:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/

Comment: This question has already been asked and answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32792163/2670182)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

function getFromDb(firstName, lastName) {

```
return connectingDb
                   .then(myDb => {
                                  myDb.collection('alon').find({
                                    "firstName": firstName,
                                    "lastName": lastName
                                  })
                   })
                   .catch(err=> { return err; })
}
```