# Store MongoDB connection into variable using Node

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to store the connection item inside a variable so that I can reuse it on other methods that perform insertion, deletion, etc.

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

let _db;

connect = function () {
    MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017", {useNewUrlParser: true}, function (err, client) {
        _db = client.db("SomeDB");
    });
};

addTestCollection = function () {
    _db.collection('Persons', function (err, collection) {

        collection.insertOne({id: 1, firstName: 'Steve', lastName: 'Jobs'});
        collection.insertOne({id: 2, firstName: 'Bill', lastName: 'Gates'});
        collection.insertOne({id: 3, firstName: 'James', lastName: 'Bond'});

        _db.collection('Persons').count(function (err, count) {
            if (err) throw err;

            console.log('Total Rows: ' + count);
        });
    });
};

connect();
addTestCollection();
```

The line that attempts to create the collection "Persons" returns a "Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined" error.

Comment: connect() function has async callback, so you access _db variable before it is assigned.

Comment: Hello @RichardSolár Thank you for your response. Do you have any recommendation on how the code should be altered in order to retrieve the connection and reuse it for other purposes?

Comment: Welcome to JS - Callback World! As you can see, almost async functions in js are  callback functions, just code js with js rule. Why you need a different way?

Comment: @GeorgiosG. I recommend you to use utils.promisify and handle connection as a promise or in a async/await. Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23771853/how-can-i-promisify-the-mongodb-native-javascript-driver-using-bluebird