# Promisify cursor execution: MongoDB Native Driver

Tags: node.js, mongodb, promise, bluebird

I already read up on these, but I'm having a bit of trouble executing it.
[mongoDB promise gets returned too early](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21732966/mongodb-promise-gets-returned-too-early/21733446#21733446)

Specifically, I'm trying to promisify the collection.find cursor, but I'm not sure I'm doing it right... any help would be appreciated:

```
//mongo.js

var promise = require('bluebird');
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var mongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
var collection = mongodb.Collection;
promise.promisifyAll(mongodb);
promise.promisifyAll(collection.prototype);

collection.prototype._find = collection.prototype.find;
collection.prototype.find = function() {
  var cursor = this._find.apply(this, arguments);
  cursor.toArrayAsync = promise.promisify(cursor.toArray, cursor);
 return cursor;
};


var myfunction = function(callback){
  // configure and export database (async)
  mongoClient.connectAsync(database)
  .then(function(db){
    module.exports.db = db;
    promise.all([
      db.createCollectionAsync('hoth', {w:1})
        .then(function(collection){
          module.exports.hoth = collection;
          collection.ensureIndexAsync({time:-1, location:'2dsphere'})
          .done(function(index){console.log(index+' hoth');});
        }),
      db.createCollectionAsync('endor', {w:1})
        .then(function(collection){
          module.exports.endor = collection;
          collection.ensureIndexAsync({time:-1, location:'2dsphere'})
          .done(function(index){console.log(index+' endor');});
        }),
      db.createCollectionAsync('alderaan', {w:1})
        .then(function(collection){
          module.exports.alderaan = collection;
          collection.ensureIndexAsync({time:-1, location:'2dsphere'})
          .done(function(index){console.log(index+' alderaan');});
        })
    ])
    .done(function(){callback(null);});
  });
};
module.exports.myfunctionAsync = promise.promisify(myfunction);
```

and here's app.js

```
// app.js
mongo.myfunctionAsync()
.then(function(result){
  mongo.hoth.mapReduceAsync(u.map, u.reduce,{
  out: {replace:'deathstar'}, scope:{size:0.01},
  query: {time:{$gte:ago}}, finalize:u.finalize});
}).then(function(deathstar){
  deathstar.findAsync({},{fields:{_id:0, value:1}});
}).then(function(docs){
  var final = _.map(docs, function(doc){return doc.value;});
}).then(function(final){
  mongo.alderaan.insertAsync(final, {w:1});
}).then(console.log('done'));
```

and here's the error

```
Cannot call method 'findAsync' of undefined
```

Comment: Just so you know, promises work by chaining through _return values_ (just like sync code!) so you should `return mongo.hoth....` and `return deathstar.findAsync(...` etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With bluebird 2.0 you can just promisify the npm. After that cursor is promisified too.

Here is a general example with a cursor:

```
var MongoClient = require('bluebird').promisifyAll(require("mongodb")).MongoClient;
```

Then:

```
MongoClient.connectAsync("mongodb://localhost:27017/something")
    .then(function(db) {
        db.collection('foo').findAsync({ })
            .then(function(cursor) {       
                return cursor.toArrayAsync();
            })
           .then(function(arrayOfFoos) {
               console.log(arrayOfFoos);
           });
    });
```