# How can I Promisify Node's mongodb module for cursors and/or a collections' toArray() using Bluebird?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, node-mongodb-native, bluebird

Relevant packages:

```
"dependencies": {
  "mongodb":    "1.4.x",
  "bluebird":   "2.3.x"
}
```

I've looked at:

- [How can I promisify the MongoDB native Javascript driver using bluebird?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23771853/438992)
- [Bluebird Promisfy.each, with for-loops and if-statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25110099/438992)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/21733446/438992
- Bluebird's promisification docs
- A few other places

I'm stuck after the `findAsync({})`.

I'd *prefer* a cursor, but it's rare I'd have too much to call `toArray()`.

It's also possible I'm doing this completely wrong.

```
MongoClient.connectAsync('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/sr')
  .then(function(_db) {
    db = _db;
    return db.collectionAsync('posts');
  })
  .then(function(colPosts) {
    return colPosts.findAsync({});
  })
  .then ( A MIRACLE OCCURS )
  .catch(function(e) {
    console.log(e);
  })
  .finally(function() {
    if (db) db.close();
  });
```

Where the miracle occurs I want to either iterate over the cursor results or the arrayified collection. I'm having problems figuring out how to go about this.

Comment: Iterate over them, and do what? Where should the results go to?

Comment: @Bergi Right now it's primarily for side-effects.

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24870812/promisify-cursor-execution-mongodb-native-driver

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, `.findAsync` returns a promise for a cursor. If you want to pull the data into memory (as with `.toArray`) I think what you're looking for is something like:

```
MongoClient.connectAsync('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/sr')
  .then(function(_db) {
    db = _db;

    return db
      .collection('posts')
      .find({})
      .limit(limit)
      .sort(sort)
      .toArrayAsync();
  })
  .then(function(posts) {
    console.log('posts', posts);
  })
  .catch(function(e) {
    console.log(e);
  });
```